# why dataframe and numpy have different calculating result?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two list (b and a), and i want to calculate:

((b*a).mean() - b.mean()*a.mean())/b.var()

but i found when i calculate it by numpy array and dataframe, result are different.

here is the example:

```
In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: a = np.array([-0.00175439,-0.00291667,-0.0025715,-0.00128452,-0.00127497,0.00784314,0.000383289,-0.00310559,0.00207397,-0.00888374,0.000996512,-0.0028754])

In [5]: b = np.array([0.00912033,-0.0025,-0.00151476,0.00452196,-0.00378788,0.0207834,0.00543689,0.00124961,-0.0105156,-0.00227187,0.00299252,0.0032175])

In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame([b, a]).T

In [7]: df.columns = ['x', 'y']

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
           x         y
0   0.009120 -0.001754
1  -0.002500 -0.002917
2  -0.001515 -0.002572
3   0.004522 -0.001285
4  -0.003788 -0.001275
5   0.020783  0.007843
6   0.005437  0.000383
7   0.001250 -0.003106
8  -0.010516  0.002074
9  -0.002272 -0.008884
10  0.002993  0.000997
11  0.003217 -0.002875

In [9]: ((df['x']*df['y']).mean() - df['x'].mean()*df['y'].mean())/df['x'].var()
Out[9]: 0.24437326863836667

In [10]: ((b*a).mean() - b.mean()*a.mean())/b.var()
Out[10]: 0.26658902033276366
```

it reallys confuse me, because that means dataframe is a unsafe datastructure, i think there must be some reason, can anyone help on this?

and why pandas make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference is default values of `degree of freedom` for `var` in numpy and pandas, `ddof=0` in numpy, `ddof=1` in pandas:

```
print(((df['x']*df['y']).mean() - df['x'].mean()*df['y'].mean())/df['x'].var())
0.24437326863836667

print (((b*a).mean() - b.mean()*a.mean())/b.var(ddof=1))
0.24437326863836667
```

---

```
print(((df['x']*df['y']).mean() - df['x'].mean()*df['y'].mean())/df['x'].var(ddof=0))
0.26658902033276366

print (((b*a).mean() - b.mean()*a.mean())/b.var())
0.26658902033276366
```